# Cannot change the ActiveConnection property of a Recordset object

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic, ado

I'm trying to open a recordset such that I can get an accurate value for `RecordCount`. I have some code that successfully does this by using `Recordset.Open` with the `adOpenStatic` and `adLockReadOnly` constants. However, when I use the following code.

```
With cmd
    .ActiveConnection = db
    .CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
    .CommandText = "doGetBookingCrewDetails"

    .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@bookingid", adInteger, adParamInput)
    .Parameters("@bookingid") = 42943

    .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@starttime", adDBTimeStamp, adParamInput)
    .Parameters("@starttime") = "07/10/2016 00:00"
End With

Set rsCr = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
rsCr.Open cmd, db, adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly
```

I get the error

> 0x800a0e7b - ADODB.Recordset: Cannot change the ActiveConnection property of a Recordset object which has a Command object as its source.

The above code returns the correct set of results when using `Command.Execute`, but then I can't specify the constants that seem to make the row count property work.

How do I make this work?

Comment: This page: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms675544(v=vs.85).aspx says this: _The ActiveConnection property is read-only for Recordset objects whose Source property is set to a valid Command object, even if the Recordset object is not open._
 It also says the `activeconnection` parameter is optional. So in short, try _not_ passing `db` into `rsCr.open` at all.

Comment: Yes, your suggestion works. I thought I'd tried that actually, guess not!

Comment: The link also says, "If you pass a Command object in the Source argument and also pass an ActiveConnection argument, an error occurs. The ActiveConnection property of the Command object must already be set to a valid Connection object or connection string."

Comment: Thanks for returning with a solution. Why don't you add it as an answer and accept it.

Comment: I thought I'd give you chance to claim the glory. Its your solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some points from [*Open Method (ADO Recordset)*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms675544.aspx):

> The ActiveConnection property is read-only for Recordset objects whose Source property is set to a valid Command object, even if the Recordset object is not open.

and

> the activeconnection parameter is optional.

also

> If you pass a Command object in the Source argument and also pass an ActiveConnection argument, an error occurs. The ActiveConnection property of the Command object must already be set to a valid Connection object or connection string

So in short, try not passing `db` into `rsCr.open` at all.

Something like this:

```
rsCr.Open cmd, , adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly
```